Foundry Compile Error
Error: Compiler error (C:\Users\circleci\project\libsolidity\codegen\CompilerUtils.cpp:1459):Stack too deep. Try compiling with --via-ir (cli) or the
equivalent viaIR: true (standard JSON) while enabling the optimizer. Otherwise, try removing local variables.
CompilerError: Stack too deep. Try compiling with --via-ir (cli) or the equivalent viaIR: true (standard JSON) while enabling the optimizer. Otherwise, try removing local variables.

As mentioned in the error, use --via-ir flag with the compile command.

Funny, i'm facing the same issue.
It's likely because you have too many local variables
Here are answers I found:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74578910/how-to-fix-compilererror-stack-too-deep-try-compiling-with-via-ir-cli
And indeed, i had a struct with too many variables. I reduced it (with an array, instead of 5 separate values) and it got fixed !

I stopped using array inside struct too. But still getting the same error and I need to have too many variables inside struct and locally so I just run with "--via-ir" that works fine for now will look into it more in future. I look into foundry book might get something from there.
